# Using Case Select in a Select SQL Query

Tags: sql, ms-access, case

```
SELECT
  CASE Forms!FormName!ComboBox
   WHEN  Is Not Null THEN (ParentTable.Column)
     FROM (Parent)
      WHERE (((ParentTable.Column)=Forms!FormName!ComboBox))
  ELSE
   ((ParentTable.Column) FROM Parent END;
```

Okay, I have a form that displays records from the parent table and I want to be able to filter it. So what the SQL code above is trying to accomplish is to say that if there is a selection made in the combo box then select only the records that match that field. The else case is that the field is null and it just selects all records. I am not very familiar with SQL code so please explain different parameters used if possible.

Or is it possible that I could use some sort of if statement instead?

Comment: What implementation of `SQL`?  Oracle, Sql server, MySQl, PostGres?

Comment: That SQL looks broken. There's at least missing and duplicated brackets.

Comment: i'm using sql in microsoft access

Comment: You're not using *that* SQL in Access as there's no CASE/WHEN/ELSE in Jet/ACE's SQL dialect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NOTE: I assume you are binding the value of Forms!FormName!ComboBox parameter dynamically.

For MS Access

```
   SELECT <YOUR_SELECT_LIST>
     FROM ParentTable 
    WHERE NZ(Forms!FormName!ComboBox,  ParentTable.Column) = ParentTable.Column
```

For SQL Server

```
   SELECT <YOUR_SELECT_LIST>
     FROM ParentTable 
    WHERE ISNULL(Forms!FormName!ComboBox,  ParentTable.Column) = ParentTable.Column
```

For ORACLE

```
   SELECT <YOUR_SELECT_LIST>
     FROM ParentTable 
    WHERE NVL(Forms!FormName!ComboBox,  ParentTable.Column) = ParentTable.Column
```

Comment: I'm using sql in microsoft access. which one is that?

Comment: Also I don't know what you mean by binding the value dynamically. I apologize for being unhelpful. 

If the value of combobox is null i want all of the records in parenttable.column and otherwise i only want those whose records match the value of combobox.

is there an if statment in sequel that can be used?

Comment: @Zack: I am not sure if your problem is resolved. If not check the updated post, specially the first query For MS Access.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use your form parameters directly in SQL.  You can parameterize your query and pass in a parameter, let's call it @FormName:

```
select
    case
         when @FormName is not null then ParentTable.column1
         else ParentTable.column2
    end
from ParentTable
where ParentTable.column3 = @FormName
```

Comment: what does @ do for that? is that personal notation or included in the code?

Comment: That's how you write parameters in sql: `declare @myParam int`: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlgetstarted/thread/e8299eb3-5d71-41ec-8459-8c42b868646b/

Answer (score 1):

Seems like CASE is not needed here:

```
SELECT ParentTable.Column
FROM ParentTable
WHERE (Forms!FormName!ComboBox IS NULL)
   OR (Forms!FormName!ComboBox = ParentTable.Column)
```